# JAVA get string between first and last occurence of a particular char

Tags: java, regex

Assuming I have this string:

```
mystring
{
    a : 1
    b : 2
    c : { e :f}
    d : x
}
```

How do I do it such that I will get only  the string  **between the first opening  curly-bracket** and **the last opening curly bracket**

As such :

```
    a : 1
    b : 2
    c : { e :f}
    d : x
```

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions in that case, as the question is posed. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ccjmne well........

Comment: @ccjmne Should I delete the regex tag?

Comment: How about "[^{]*\\{(.*)\\}[^}]*" ?

Comment: BTW u say better for opening and last opening or later closing curly brace? The example implies closing brace while the text days opening

Comment: If this is an academic exercise, use a stack for the curly braces encountered and discard any characters when the stack is empty.

Comment: If this is an academic exercise  .... wait what???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the search is done greedily. You need to find your first `{` non-greedily (`.*?`), while the capture should be done again greedily (`.*`):

```
".*?\{(.*)\}.*"
```

The full code would be:

```
String s = // your input string
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?\\{(.*)\\}.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

You could do the same thing without regex, too, using plain `String` methods:

```
int start = s.indexOf("{") + 1;
int end = s.lastIndexOf("}");
if (start > 0 && end > start) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(start, end));
}
```

Comment: which is better?

Comment: The non-regex is more simple in this simple case, but is not easy to extend if you need some further pattern matching within you String later on.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `substring()` method with parameters `indexOf('{')` and `lastIndexOf('}')` as below:

```
yourString=yourString.substring(indexOf('{'),lastIndexOf('}'));
```